# Select data from three table through joining WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Database I have three tables named wp_country,wp_schoolstudent and wp_schoolsms and have some common column names like wp_country , wp_city in these tables ( mean foreign key )  I want to chick that when the wp_schoolstudent.wp_country = wp_schoolsms.wp_country when they are equal select data from tablee like ( 'phone no' 'SMS' 'school name').
its work fine but it is from two table:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT P.wp_collage FROM {$wpdb- 
>prefix}collegestudent as EV
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}collagesms as P ON EV.wp_collage 
= P.wp_collage ";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
echo "<pre> ";
print_r($results);exit;
?>
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT wp_collagesms.wp_collage, wp_collegestudent.wp_collage,wp_collegestudent.studentphoneno,wp_collagesms.sms FROM {$wpdb->prefix}collagesms
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}collegestudent 
ON wp_collagesms.wp_collage = wp_collegestudent.wp_collage ";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
echo "<pre> ";
print_r($results);exit;

Comment: It also work but I need three table joining